# How to make post request in CURL with Perfect

Tags: swift, macos, curl, perfect

I have set up a [Perfect](http://perfect.org) server and I have written all my API but I'm stuck at the CURL, I don't know how do I set headers I have never worked before with CURL.

I am setting up a payment gateway and I want to set authorization headers and send body data but I dont know how to.

From example http://perfect.org/docs/cURL.html

```
let curlObject = CURL(url: "http://www.perfect.org")

curlObject.perform {
    code, header, body in

    print("Request error code \(code)")
    print("Response: \(curlObject.responseCode)")
    print("Header: \(header)")
    print("Body: \(body)")
}
```

I referred this but got no help how to do?

https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**After lots of searching, I found something**

```
let url = "https://httpbin.org/post"
let postParamString = "key1=value1&key2=value2"
let byteArray = [UInt8](postParamString.utf8)


let curl = CURL(url: url)

let _ = curl.setOption(CURLOPT_POST, int: 1)
let _ = curl.setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, v: UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: byteArray))
let _ = curl.setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, int: byteArray.count)

curl.perform { code, header, body in

        print("Request error code \(code) \n Response: \(curl.responseCode) \n Header: \(UTF8Encoding.encode(bytes:header)) \n Body: \(UTF8Encoding.encode(bytes: body))")

}
```

For more just refer this **C examples**
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html

Comment: Thank you! This finally fixed my problem! Just to add one thing, remember you are responsible for keeping "byteArray" in memory while it is being used. I had to add it as a global variable (temporarily) to make it work.

Comment: @gabriellanata Good to know it helped you :)

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to use CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS instead of CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS for string (s: instead of v:). Otherwise it becomes garbage text.

Answer (score 2):

UnsafeMutableRawPointer will be probably killed when you go async. This will work fine:

```
import cURL
import PerfectCURL

public class CurlHTTPRequest {

    public static func post(url: String, header: String, body: String, callback: @escaping (String)->Void) {

        let byteArray:[UInt8] = Array(body.utf8)

        let pointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: byteArray.count)
        pointer.initialize(from: byteArray, count: byteArray.count)

        let curlObject = CURL(url: url)
        curlObject.setOption(CURLOPT_POST, int: 1)
        curlObject.setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, s: header)
        curlObject.setOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, int: 0)
        curlObject.setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, v: pointer)
        curlObject.setOption(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, int: byteArray.count)

        curlObject.perform { (code, header, body) in

            curlObject.close()

            callback("Code: \(code)\n Header: \(String(bytes: header, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")\n Body: \(String(bytes: body, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")")

        }
    }
}
```